# Running MSDelta in Docker

Tags: docker, delta

I've found that the Windows file patching mechanism MSDelta creates much smaller patches than Linux alternatives like xDelta3 and bsdiff. This functionality is crucial to an application we are developing.

Is there any way to run MSDelta in a Docker container?

Comment: On a windows docker container, possibly, on a linux one, almost certainly not, as MSDelta seems to be part of the WIndows OS : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb417345(v=msdn.10)

Comment: I see, so there's no way of using something like Wine to get msDelta running then

Comment: Maybe, never tried to put wine in a container though.